# Primitive Pythagorean triples

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

> Prove that if $x = 2uv$ and $y = u^2 - v^2$, show that $(x, y, z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple if and only if $\gcd(u, v) = 1$.

The direction $\gcd(u, v) \neq 1$ implies $(x, y, z)$ is a non-primitive Pythagorean triple – this is straightforward. But I need the converse too, for which I'm completely stumped.

Comment: If $u=5, v= 3$ then $(x,y,z) = (30,16,34)$

Comment: What is $z$?${}$

Comment: $z=u^2+v^2$, as in the [general form of a Pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Sure, but the OP doesn't say that anywhere in their question. Typo?

Comment: I suppose the wording "... a Pythagorean triple $(x,y,z)$ is primitive if and only if ..." would work better, since the values of $x$ and $y$ determine the value of $z$.

Comment: @JackM: Actually I do. I say it's a Pythagorean triple. ;) This question is copied straight out of a book though, so I can't change it to suit me really.

Comment: @Neil: Fair point yeah. How odd hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the answer by Zubin Mukerjee, the result as stated is not correct. We state and prove a correct version.

**Theorem:** Let $u$ and $v$ be positive integers, with $v\lt u$. Let $x=2uv$, $y=u^2-v^2$, and $z=u^2+v^2$. Then $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple if and only if $\gcd(u,v)=1$ and $u$ and $v$ are of opposite parity.

---

It is clear that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers. It is also easy to verify that $(2uv)^2+(u^2-v^2)^2=(u^2+v^2)^2$.

(i) We show that if $\gcd(u,v)\ne 1$ or $u$ and $v$ are of the same parity, than the triple $(x,y,z)$ is not primitive. Suppose that $\gcd(u,v)=d\gt 1$. Then $d^2$ divides all of $2uv$, $u^2-v^2$, and $u^2+v^2$, so the triple $(x,y,z)$ is not primitive.

Next we show that if $u$ and $v$ are of the same parity, then $(x,y,z)$ is not primitive. This is because in that case all of $2uv$, $u^2-v^2$, and $u^2+v^2$ are even.

(ii) Next we show that if $\gcd(u,v)=1$ and $u$ and $v$ are of opposite parity, then $(x,y,z)$ is primitive.

Suppose to the contrary that some $d\gt 1$ divides both $y$ and $z$. Then some *prime* $p$ divides both $y$ and $z$. So $p$ divides $u^2-v^2$ and $p$ divides $u^2+v^2$.  Note that that since $u$ and $v$ are of opposite parity, it follows that $u^2+v^2$ is odd. So $p$ is odd.

Since $p$ divides $u^2-v^2$ and $u^2+v^2$, it follows that $p$ divides their sum and difference $2u^2$ and $2v^2$. since $p$ is odd, $p$ divides $u^2$ and $v^2$, and since $p$ is prime, $p$ divides $u$ and $v$. This contradicts the fact that $\gcd(u,v)=1$, and completes the proof.

Comment: This implicitly makes use of prime factorisation and the (generalised) Euclid's lemma... but I don't think we can help that, at least the latter! Oh well. Thanks regardless

Comment: It's worth noting that part (ii) can at least be formulated easily without proof by contradiction, by the way. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're completely stumped might be that the converse is false :)

It is *not* true that

> If $\gcd{(u,v)}=1$, then $(2uv, u^2-v^2, u^2+v^2)$ is a [primitive Pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

**Counterexample(s)**: $u=7$, $v=3$ corresponds to the triple $(42, 40, 58)$, which is clearly not primitive. Indeed, for any $u$ and $v$ both odd, every value in the triple will be even, making it non-primitive.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. But how odd. This question came out of a printed book... I would normally be loath to think it contains such an inaccuracy!

Comment: As noted by @Neil in the 1st comment.

Comment: Anyway, this suggests I might have to modify the condition on the RHS to be $(\gcd(u, v) = 1) \wedge (u\ \text{even} \oplus v\ \text{even})$, perhaps?

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime and of opposite parity, you do get a primitive triple, and you get all primitive triples in this way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Indeed. How can I show this though, using only super elementary methods? (i.e. no Euclid's lemma yet even.)

Comment: I don't know how little one can get away with.  It might be interesting to see what happens in some quadratic extensions where unique factorization fails.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Well how would you demonstrate it normally, out of curiosity?

Comment: for every primitive triple so representable, the usual. Argue $z$ is odd, then factor $z^2-y^2$, argue that each natural factor is a perfect square.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14315/discussion-between-noldorin-and-andre-nicolas)

Comment: After some negative experiences, I avoid chat. Proofs are in every book, on MSE too I am sure.

Comment: okay. well that comment posted by "me" was automated anyway heh...

Comment: I can't find a valid proof... all the ones I've seen seem to be incomplete or flawed.

Comment: For the particular question you asked here, I am surprised no none has answered a suitably modified version (opposite parity), since it is quick. The question of whether every primitive triple is so representable is different, but standard.

Comment: Actually the converse I find easier. :) I'm surprised no-one has answered either... Might have to set a bounty on this question.